# C++ primer 5 Ed Global objects

Tags: c++, global-variables

In C++ primer 5 Ed Chapter 12 The: Dynamic memory. It is said: "static objects are allocated before they
are used, and they are destroyed when the program ends."

Does this mean the global objects are defined and initialized before control passes by their declaration.

I have this example:

```
constexpr double PI = 3.14;

double Perim(double rad) {
    std::cin.get(); // I want to block here waiting for user interaction
    return rad * 2 * PI;
}

constexpr double radius = 4.16;
double perim = Perim(radius); // Perim will blcok until user presses a key
int y;
```

So above is `y` created and initialized before user presses a key or it waits until control passes by its definition?

Comment: _"...All non-local variables with static storage duration are initialized as part of program startup, before the execution of the main function begins (unless deferred, see below)...."_   see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization#Non-local_variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your posted code is in the global `namespace` then `y` will be allocated and set to `0` before `main` is run.  It can only be used, however, after the line it is declared and defined on.

Comment: Yea it is on global scope. So you mean even if `Perim` is still blocking then `y` is initialized to 0?